# single node spark cluster vs pandas

Tags: pandas, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-ecs, amazon-emr

I see spark and pandas are having similarities. But spark has parallel capabilities.

I had a project already setup by someone. I see the previous developer uses an EMR cluser with single node to run the spark jobs without any scaling etc.

I felt to simplify the situation, better  use pandas on a ECS task instead of EMR and single node.

Can someone suggest will my pandas on ECS task same as EMR and single node.

Answer (score 1):

To start with, firstly there is a lot of differences in between `Pandas` and `Spark` besides just `Spark` having parallel capabilities. Here are a few major ones:

1. Spark Dataframes work in distributed manned compared to Pandas Dataframes. Yes, both are in-memory dataframes but it's completely different how they work.
2. Spark Dataframes are `lazily evaluated` which basically means that it doesn't execute until and unless an `action` is called and all the `transformations` that you have provided are created into a DAG.
3. When you use Spark Dataframes, all the steps that you have mentioned before executions are converted into an `optimized plan` by Spark itself and you get many other capabilities like `AQE(Adaptive Query Execution)`,`DPP (Dynamic Partition Pruning)` and much more than a Pandas dataframe can provide.

To answer your question, in short NO, it's not the same using Spark with a single cluster and Pandas on ECS because even if you use Spark in a single node cluster it's gonna use all the cores available in the machine to provide you with distributed processing, the typical answer is `it depends`. It depends on

- what are you trying to do in the project?
- how much data are you dealing with?
- Is data volume gonna remain constant or is it's gonna increase with time?
- Is high performance and fault tolerance are you what really looking for?

This is a wider topic to cover all points here. Both have their place in the data processing world, it entirely depends on the use case you have.

Comment: ok. So spark will try to parallelize using cores... thanks